# Is there a way to modify TreeView node is met criteria

Tags: xml, treeview

I am using XML file as data source for TreeView. It workes well, however I wonder whether there is any way to add parameter to TreeView A HREF link if there is `external="1"` parameter in XML record:

```
<SubMenu text="TEST" type="href" external="1" prikaz="something" value="712"></SubMenu>
```

and ASP.NET TreeView:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="objTreeViewMenu" runat="server" ExpandDepth="0" ImageSet="Arrows" ShowExpandCollapse="true">
   <DataBindings>
       <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Home" TextField="#Name" ValueField="#Value" />
       <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Menu" TextField="text" ValueField="value" />
       <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="SubMenu" TextField="text" ValueField="value" />
   </DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Is there a way to use `TreeNodeDataBound` to modify every TreeView node if paramater `external` in XML file?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question, hopefully someone can find this helpful

```
protected void TreeNodeBound(Object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
     XmlElement dr = (XmlElement)e.Node.DataItem;
     if (dr.HasAttribute("external"))
     {
         e.Node.Target = "external";
         e.Node.NavigateUrl = dr.Attributes["prikaz"].Value;
     }
}
```